# java api to generate an image (not swing)

Tags: java, image, server

I need a java api that can generate an image (preferably a tiff image) on a java server (weblogic if that matters) from a text file (preferably from styled html). I do not want to use AWT or swing. For obvious reasons swing is not appropriate for server side development (first and foremost it is single threaded). I assumed this would be something readily available but seems like it does not exist or Im looking for the wrong thing on google. Anyone know of an API I could use?

Comment: Voting to close as off topic as this is asking for tooling suggestions.

Comment: "generate an image ... from a text file" – meaning render the text contents? try googling that

Comment: graphics processing generally can't be done on most servers, as most servers lack graphics cards.

Comment: Why does it matter that swing is `single threaded`. Why not use a `BufferedImage`? It is awt, but does that mean you have to start the edt?

Comment: `ImageIO` and the Advanced Imaging API <- No threads, no UI, just pure image manipulation

Comment: Yes of course I googled it. You try googling it you wont find anything either.

Comment: server side processing for multiple parallel requests. Do I really need to explain why single threaded is bad ... What if say more than one person tries to use the website at once... performance ... queued .... etc

Comment: ImageIO is synchronized (so basically single theaded) but thank you for being the first to try and provide something usefull.

Comment: who said anything about a graphics card. I need to generate an image not display an image on the server. I need to generate an image so I can send it to another application that requires an image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

sigh. I'm losing faith in this website. Every post I read by anyone the first comment is that it is off topic. People just look for every chance to call something offtopic? I want a java api. Is this not the place to ask a java related question?

The solution is we are going to use apache pdfbox to generate the image.
1. build a pdf from the text input using apache pdfbox
2. use PDPage.convertToImage() to generate jpg
3. convert to tiff

Comment: There's a rule that this site is for programming questions, not for "I am searching a library" question. There's another site for that (can't remember which one). Btw if you're starting with PDFBox, use the latest version. `PDPage.convertToImage()` indicates you're using 1.8.* or earlier.

Comment: once again how is this not a programming question. I have HTML and I want to generate a TIFF. This is a programming question. Problem is solved but I grow ever weary of this website.

Comment: Programming questions are the ones answered with code. Read the rules here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic